# When trying to access a value from key, getting `[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)

Tags: ruby, api, fullcontact

So I am using Full Contact api to fill in information about certain companies. I am trying to create an array of values for two keys: "lookupDomain" and "orgName" which (from my understanding) are located in the hash lookupDomain.

Here is a snippet of my code for the RestClient.post request and a method for creating the array @parsed_output:

```
def get_org_info(company_name)
        response = RestClient.post("https://api.fullcontact.com/v3/company.search",{"companyName" => "#{company_name}",}.to_json, {content_type: :json, accept: :json, :authorization => "Bearer SECRET KEY"})
        JSON.parse(response.body)
    end

    def parse_org_info(info_output)
        @parsed_output << {lookupDomain: info_output["lookupDomain"], lookupDomain: info_output["orgName"]}
        p @parsed_output
    end
```

I keep getting the response:

```
`[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. **I have also tried** putting in numbers that should index the object in the hash I want but I just get an output of everything (i.e location, logo, etc.)

Thank you in advanced for any help! Please forgive me if this is an obvious mistake, I am very new to this.

Thank you

Comment: Where does this error point to? Is it `info_output["lookupDomain"]` which raises this error? If so, maybe `info_output` is an Array?

Comment: @MarekLipka it points to that line yes, (@parsed_output << ....)

Comment: So, maybe what's `info_output`? Is it an array?

Comment: @MarekLipka it should be a hash, based on the output of the RestClient response.

Comment: Non sequitur, I would confirm it's a hash in `parse_org_info` directly.

Comment: @MarekLipka looks to be a hash!

Comment: I'm really sorry, I'm new to this. I did info_output. is_a? Array and got true. when I do the same for @parsed_output, it is also an array.